# Selecting according to the sum of a certain's row's column conditionally in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume we got a table like this:

```
id   other_id   limit   
......................
1     1          4
2     1          5
3     2          3
4     2          2
```

Assume we got a total limit of 5 and other_id 1, is there any way I can get IDs `3,4` from the table above?
More conditions:

- total limit = 3, other_id = 1 => IDs of `1` rows return
- total limit = 9, other_id = 1 => IDs of `1,2` rows return
- total limit = 10, other_id = 1,2 => IDs of `1,2,3` rows return
- total limit = 15, other_id = 1,2 => IDs of `1,2,3,4` rows return
- total limit = 3, other_id = 2 => IDs of `3` rows return
- total limit = 4, other_id = 2 => IDs of `3,4` rows return

The third one is obviously unexpected, but I would be able to handle the error in a different way (total limit being more than the total of limits in the table)

Comment: you changed your question, for that you should make another question

Answer (score 0):

You want a rolling total. MySql supports window functions  since version 8.0. Limit is a reserved word, using `climit` for the column name

```
select id, climit
from (
    select *, sum(climit) over(order by id) s
    from mytable
) t
where s - climit < myLimitParameter;
```

Comment: This didn't work when I put an additional `WHERE IN` clause to it, edited my post (tried `where s - climit < myLimitParameter and other_id in (1);` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in mysql 5.x and above you can do a correlated query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1( id int, `other_id` int,  limits int);
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES
> (1,  1,   4),                 
> (2,  1,   5),                   
> (3,  2,   3),                      
> (4,  2,   2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
> FROM
> (SELECT t.id, t.other_id
> , (SELECT SUM(limits) FROM tab1 WHERE limits > t.limits OR (id < t.id AND limits = t.limits) 
> OR (id = t.id)) required
> FROM tab1 t
> HAVING required <= '12'
> ORDER BY  id,other_id ASC) t1
> ```

> ```
> | GROUP_CONCAT(id) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1,2,3            |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4bd3ac45ea2f46f7ef28067021e99f32)*